# Scraping Python Captcha

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy, captcha

I am planning to use Selenium (python).

I am trying to scrape a result of search page after Captcha input. I haven't worked on the captcha stuff before. I searched a bit but didn't find any concrete end-to-end example. Few options suggested were like to use pytesseract package & download the image, then convert to string, and get its value. But this captcha changes with every refresh. And also, the captcha becomes invalid after sometime. Can i bypass this captcha if it is possible with selenium? Or looking for some alternative ways.

The sample UI is as below
[image]

Can i achieve it with beautifulSoup or scrapy instead of selenium?

Any help with example is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't bypass the captcha until unless you find a loophole, which would quite less. So what you need to do is already what you mentioned `use pytesseract package & download the image, then convert to string, and get its value`

Comment: if you can automate a captcha, then that captcha fails to be a good captcha.

Comment: okay tarun, cruisepandey

Comment: http://sangaline.com/post/advanced-web-scraping-tutorial/

Comment: Zipru is not a real site. So, i can't follow the tutorial @YashPokar

Answer (score 0):

You can try this project [captcha breaker](https://github.com/JanPalasek/ulozto-captcha-breaker), which uses `tensorflow` ai to break [uloz.to](https://uloz.to/) codes.

You'll probably have to train your own model (your captcha has different parameters, such as number of letters, case compliance), but it might be a good start.